# changing oil for the first time on Kawasaki ER6N and need advice?

Tags: oil-change

I've not long had my bike and I'm just getting into motorbikes, i have a Kawasaki ER6N and just bought some oil as I'm not sure when the oil was last changed, as i bought the bike about a week ago.

My question is, from reading the manual it says i need a torque wrench to put the drian bolt back on, Well i don't have one and do i really need one for this? Also i only have 1L of oil, is that enough? And do i need to replace the oil filter as well or can i leave that for now? I just really want to get the oil changed.

Comment: Drain plugs go on "good 'n tight", no torque wrench needed.

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need a torque wrench, however a torque wrench does help as it allows you to tighten nuts & bolts to manufacturers specifications, so the chances of stripping the threads is greatly reduced.. Just don't over tighten the sump bolt.

As for the oil filter.. Yes you should really replace it. There's not really much point in changing the oil if your going to contaminate it immediately by filtering your new oil through an old filter. 
As regards the amount of oil, specs says the Kawasaki ER6N takes 2.4 litres of oil once drained, so no, 1 litre is not enough for an oil change.

There is usually a sight glass or dipstick on a bike so that you can check the level is correct. Check the level with the bike upright on level ground, NOT on its side-stand etc unless otherwise stated in the handbook.